# Error 3075 in Select Query

Tags: sql, select

Query gives Syntax error missing operator in query '[Relationship Manager]=John DOE'

```
BCA_Source = " SELECT distinct [Account Data Table less DTA CHD].BCA_ICA, " _
            & "[Account Data Table less DTA CHD].[Relationship Manager]" _
            & " FROM [Account Data Table less DTA CHD] " _
            & " WHERE [Relationship Manager]= " _
            & Me.cmb_Mngr.Value,
```

Thanks,
Sury

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: And is this vb6/vbscript or vb.net?

Comment: @David: a quick google search on the error indicates it's an access issue.

Comment: Hi Joel,
Can you please let me know the fix for this error in Access DB.

Comment: I did try the escape quotes on for Me.cmb_Mngr.value, but it still gives an error

Answer (score 3):

Initial guess would be that **Me.cmb_Mngr.Value** has to be wrapped with escaped quotes.

Comment: Of course, that wouldn't be an issue if he used a QUERY PARAMETER!